# How to choose the potential hyperparameters for GridSearchCV on RandomForestClassifier? Will default always be the best?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn, hyperparameter

I'm fairly new to machine learning, and I know similar questions have been asked but I can't find an answer that satisfies my curiosity. I'm working on a Random Forest Classifier model in python, and I am trying to use GridSearchCV to tune the hyperparameters. At first I ran the classifier class with default params and got a score on the test data of 0.890, about equal to the OOB score. I was pretty happy with that result but wanted to go ahead with hyperparameter tuning anyway. I used GridSearchCV with the following dictionary:

```
{'criterion':['gini', 'entropy'],
 'class_weight':[None, 'balanced'],
 'min_samples_split':[12, 30, 48],
 'max_depth': [x for x in range(5,11)],
 'min_samples_leaf': [x for x in range(3, 19, 3)]}
```

But ultimately, the best score from this grid was only 0.851, and the best estimator used all the parameters at their extremes: `min_samples_split=12, max_depth=10, min_samples_leaf=3`. So in retrospect, I'm thinking "duh" because it makes perfect sense that the best model would go to a greater depth, have the fewest samples per leaf, etc. But it leaves me confused about tuning parameters as a concept. Will this always be true that the less limited a model is, the better it performs? Did I pick reasonable parameter options? Is there a problem with using default parameters? I know it can be costly with really large data, but the df I'm working with only has ~40k entries (train and test combined), so is that okay?

Comment: Are your records indepedent? If so, then it sounds like what you're doing is reasonable, but it's not possible to say for sure without seeing your code and data. You may want to check other scores to help ensure you're not overfitting, and you may want to check the test scores to help find the model with the lowest variance.